# Error mapping optionset on CRM 365 virtual entities

Tags: odata, dynamics-crm-365

When mapping an optionset on a virtual entity to its external data source got the following error:

```
Type mismatch of the external attribute of type ‘System.Nullable`1[System.Int32]’ expected a 'System.Nullable`1[[System.Int32, Microsoft.Xrm.DataProvider.OData.614d0bd27de7e9119c27005056876672.e98901a683e7e9119c27005056876672, Version=1.1.20.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null]]'
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: can you add some more information like metadata of your source Odata feed.
Error clearly states Type mismatch, are you using Two optionset or multi option set.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamics365/customerengagement/on-premises/customize/virtual-entity-odata-provider-requirements#data-type-mapping

Comment: @AnkUser using optionset and the data source type is int32

Comment: Sounds like you may have set the required level of the option set field to `required`.

Comment: @RyanJames both are nullable as stated in the error text!

Comment: Shane_yo answer worked for me

Answer (score 1):

one cannot map using Int32, hence your error. Using virtual entities in D365 one has to use an enumeration for setting up and mapping optionsets. View the schema from your odata endpoint using `$metadata`:

example : https://yourowndatasource.azurewebsites.net/$metadata

it will return something like the below, find your defined schema `enumtypes` :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<edmx:Edmx Version="4.0" xmlns:edmx="http://docs.oasis-open.org/odata/ns/edmx">
  <edmx:DataServices>
    <Schema Namespace="AK.IG.VirtualEntity.DataSource.Models" xmlns="http://docs.oasis-open.org/odata/ns/edm">
      <EnumType Name="ak_Lead_EventTypeCode">
          <Member Name="EugenesCode" Value="777" />
          <Member Name="LeadSource" Value="007" />
          <Member Name="LeadGenProcess" value="101" /> 
...

      </EnumType>
    </Schema> 
  </edmx:DataServices>
</edmx:Edmx>
```

With that use exactly the naming convention :
[image: OptionSet mapping]

1. EnumType.Name
2. Member Name

Comment: Thanks Shane, this is not well documented by MS as of now as far as I can see. Do you see anything documenting this by MS?

Comment: this worked great for me btw

Comment: nope not well documented at all, think there's a caveat somewhere about the enums.